# How to include header files in external library in CMake

Tags: c, build, cmake, raspberry-pi

I have a C application which is running on Raspberry Pi 3 and currently, I have to build it on PI with Cmake. I am trying to build it on Ubuntu machine. I have added a CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE as described [here](https://medium.com/@au42/the-useful-raspberrypi-cross-compile-guide-ea56054de187).
I could run `cmake. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` without any problem but the "make" command is not successful and it can not find a header file inside one of the external library: "mirsdrapi-rsp". The error message is:

```
fatal error: mirsdrapi-rsp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mirsdrapi-rsp.h"
                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have created a folder named "lib" and have put the "libmirsdrapi-rsp.so" file inside it. 
my CMakeLists.txt is as below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -v -g -D_XOPEN_SOURCE")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -v ")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-v")
set (SDR_API_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
include_directories (include ${SDR_API_PATH})

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")

find_library(mirslocation NAMES mirsdrapi-rsp HINTS ${SDR_API_PATH} NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
message(STATUS ${mirslocation})

add_library(mirs STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mirs PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${mirslocation})

target_link_libraries (raspberryPiDaemon mirs)
target_link_libraries(raspberryPiDaemon m)
```

Cmake is printing the right path of the library mirsdrapi-rsp while running "find_library" and as I mentioned I am getting the error message just while running "make" command and not "cmake" command.
My content of CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE is as below:

```
# Define our host system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Define the cross compiler locations
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)

# Define the sysroot path for the RaspberryPi distribution in our tools folder 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/SET)


# Use our definitions for compiler tools
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# Search for libraries and headers in the target directories only
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)

add_definitions(-Wall -std=c11)
```

Anybody knows how I can add the header file from mirsdrapi-rsp library to include path?

Comment: Can you check mirsdrapi-rsp.h exist in your system using find or grep command? Have you installed the SDRplay in your Linux system? Perhaps you should find the header file like this `/usr/local/include/mirsdrapi-rsp.h` ?

Comment: @danglingpointer you were right. I put mirsdrapi-rsp.h inside lib/include and included it and it passed the error but now I am getting this error: aspberrypi/lib/libmirsdrapi-rsp.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: file format not recognised, are you sure that *.so file is built in your system or that so lib has any sym links to other lib?

Comment: @danglingpointer I copied so file from raspberry pi /usr/local/lib. It is working when I am building on pi? Should I have so file built for target machine or so file built on my build machie (ubunto)?

Comment: Yes, use the command  `file "yourlib.so"` it will give the machine target where the lib is built against it.  Do you want SDRplay to run in your host machine x86 or  your building in your host machine x86 for ARM i.e cross compiling in this case you just delete the file and it will create that so file?

Comment: thank @danglingpointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're setting include_directories to the wrong path (it is set 2 times to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib which must be the folder of libraries not the header files). Check again the correct location of the missing header file.

More precisely: you need to find the path of mirsdrapi-rsp.h and let CMake know it just like for find_library:

```
find_path(MIRSDRAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES mirsdrapi-rsp.h PATHS {proper-location})

if (MIRSDRAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  target_include_directories(raspberryPiDaemon PRIVATE ${MIRSDRAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

In addition, you can set the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property to the library like this:

```
set_property(TARGET mirsdrapi-rsp APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${MIRSDRAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

This way, target_include_directories might be unnecessary and target_link_directories should be enough.